# Rails: how to run a model callback function in the background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `after_create :get_geolocation` function that runs after a new user is created.

1. **Is there a way I can run this function in the background so that there is no delay for the user?** Since if the geolocation service
   being used is down, it will break signups.
2. Models can't seem to call `request.remote_ip`. Could this function
   be somehow moved into a controller for `request.remote_ip` to work?

Comment: You can use something like delayed_job or sidekiq.

Comment: Is this Rails 3 or Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/), [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), or another asynchronous task utility to perform the geolocation in the background. And for the IP, you could either store it in the model or send it along with your queue request.